# How to deep-copy a QGIS memory layer?

Tags: pyqgis

I struggle with creating a deep copy of a memory layer in QGIS. Whenever I modify the layer copy, the original gets modified, too. Can anybody point me to the mistake I am making in the following code:

```
def createMemoryLayer(self, layerName, sourceLayer):
    # create empty memory layer
    memoryLayer = QgsVectorLayer(
        QgsWkbTypes.geometryDisplayString(sourceLayer.geometryType()) +
        "?crs=" + sourceLayer.crs().authid() +
        "&index=yes",
        layerName,
        "memory"
    )
    memoryLayerDataProvider = memoryLayer.dataProvider()

    # copy the table structure
    memoryLayer.startEditing()
    memoryLayerDataProvider.addAttributes(
        sourceLayer.fields().toList()
    )
    memoryLayer.commitChanges()

    # copy the features
    #memoryLayerDataProvider.addFeatures(
    #    [QgsFeature(feature) for feature in sourceLayer.getFeatures()]
    #)

    # DEEP copy the features
    features= []
    for feature in sourceLayer.getFeatures():
        f = QgsFeature(feature)
        f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(feature.geometry()))
        features.append(f)
    memoryLayerDataProvider.addFeatures(features)

    return memoryLayer
```

see the commented-out lines for what I had thought to fix with the lines thereafter. 
According to the API docs, `QgsFeature(QgsFeature)` and `QgsGeometry(QgsGeometry)` both create deep copy of the original object.

Any clues?

Comment: tested in QGIS 2.18.x and 2.99.x

Comment: In QGIS 2.18.4 I changed line 4/5 in `"Polygon?crs=" + sourceLayer.crs().authid() +`, then used `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(createMemoryLayer(None, 'dest', QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('source')[0]))` interactively to copy a memory polygon layer. I could then edit both layers independently. Which szenario did you test?

Comment: My use case is copying an input layer to a “work” layer, on which a plugin processes in a separate `QThread`. Note that I only add it to the `mapLayerRegistry` after the processing has finished. 

The curious thing is that it seems to depend on whether the original layer is a memory layer too (all works as expected, if the input layer is a shape file)

Just compiling qgis-2.18 to test your code, thanks!

Comment: I just stumbled over a first bread crump directing me into the right direction: the `QgsAbstractGeometry` objects remain the same – even if the `QgsFeature`s and `QgsGeometry`s change. `[repr(f.geometry().geometry()) for f in memoryLayer.getFeatures()]`and `[repr(f.geometry().geometry()) for f in sourceLayer.getFeatures()]` return the same memory addresses. Working on it – I’m going to report back once I know more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

The error was not in the code presented. Rather, later on, I modified the features’ `QgsAbstractGeometry` without first creating a deep copy of it. The trick is the `.clone()`:

```
abstractGeometry = feature.geometry().geometry().clone()
# … do something with the geometry
feature.setGeometry(abstractGeometry)
```

#### long answer

I still have not figured out how exactly QGIS copies layers/features/geometries/abstractGeometries.

It seems though, that upon copying a `QgsMemoryLayer`’s features to another `QgsMemoryLayer`, the `QgsAbstractGeometry`s are kept as mere references and in effect point to the same place in memory.

My plugin’s script then changed single vertices of the `QgsAbstractGeometry`s:

```
abstractGeometry = features[featureId].geometry()
abstractGeometry.moveVertex(
    QgsVertexId(p, r, v, QgsVertexId.SegmentVertex),
    QgsPointV2(x, y)
)
features[featureId].setGeometry(abstractGeometry)
```

… and by that inadvertently changed the `QgsAbstractGeometry` which actually was shared between the original and the copied memory layer.

There is nothing to be changed in the code listed in the question. Rather, a deep copy of the `QgsAbstractGeometry` is needed before it is modified (by calling its `clone()` method). The above code needs only minor modification:

`abstractGeometry = features[featureId].geometry().clone()
abstractGeometry.moveVertex(
    QgsVertexId(p, r, v, QgsVertexId.SegmentVertex),
    QgsPointV2(x, y)
)
features[featureId].setGeometry(abstractGeometry)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to start an edit session for copying attributes/features.  After adding the attributes you should update the fields and I think your also over complicating adding the features, try:

```
# copy the table structure
memoryLayerDataProvider.addAttributes(sourceLayer.fields().toList())
memoryLayer.updateFields()

features= []
for feature in sourceLayer.getFeatures():
    features.append(feature)
memoryLayerDataProvider.addFeatures(features)
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not address my question. I know how to create a memory layer in general, and your for-loop just replaces my pythonic list comprehension. 
Thanks for reminding me of the `updateFields()` method, though.